# javascript addEventListener browser variability

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am in the process of creating my own audio-element controllers. In Chrome and Opera, this code:

`audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", seekTimeUpdate, false);`

seems to be invoking `seekTimeUpdate` on page load, causing the time text to display. Not so for Firefox and IE11, for which I must invoke it independently.

Why? I know there are differences in how javascript works in different browsers, but it would be useful to understand more.

The offending function:

```
function seekTimeUpdate() {
    var nt = audio.currentTime * (100/audio.duration);
    seekSlider.value = nt;
    var curMins = Math.floor(audio.currentTime / 60);
    var curSecs = Math.floor(audio.currentTime - curMins * 60);
    var durMins = Math.floor(audio.duration / 60);
    var durSecs = Math.floor(audio.duration - durMins * 60);
    if (curSecs < 10) curSecs = "0"+curSecs;
    if (durSecs < 10) durSecs = "0"+durSecs;
    if (nt==0) {
        timeTxt.innerHTML = durMins+":"+durSecs;
    } else {
        timeTxt.innerHTML = curMins+":"+curSecs; 
    }
}
```